# Start a new line after the first page

Tags: line-breaking

The command to start a new line in LaTeX is `\\`. It works well on the first page of my document, but from the second onwards no longer works. Does anybody tell me why?

This is the code: https://nopaste.me/view/36b8819f#L61

I used the nopaste service 'cause the code is a bit long, and I didn't want make a wall text

Comment: rather than post an external link please make a small example inline in the question.

Comment: You're starting from a false premise: the command for starting a new line is *not* ``\\``, but “leaving a blank line”.

Comment: You appear to be giving up on using `center` environments on page 2. Is this intentional?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions, made in no particular order:

- If you don't want indentation of the first line of a paragraph, you should set the `\parskip` parameter to a nonzero length; otherwise, it's really hard for readers to tell when a paragraph begins.
- Use blank lines to create paragraph breaks. For sure, don't use `\\` to induce paragraph breaks.
- Do get rid of the `\par` statements before each `center` environment: `center` automatically inserts `\par` statements at the start and end of the environment.
- The only instance when you do need to use `\\` is to create a *line break* (not a paragraph break) between two consecutive schemes.
- Instead of embedding the entire document in a `flushleft` environment, consider issuing the directive `\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`.
- Is there an over-arching theme that's organizing the color choices? On the first page alone, there's red, brown, green, violet, blue, and cyan. Add a couple of font size changes, and the document will start to look like a ransom note...

---

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- new
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=10mm,bindingoffset=15mm,heightrounded}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setarrowdefault{0,1,black}
\setarrowlabelsep{2pt}
\setcompoundsep{3em}
\setarrowoffset{4pt}
%%\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}           % <--- new

\setlength\parindent{0pt}             % <--- new
\setlength\parskip{0.75\baselineskip} % <--- new

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textcolor{red}{REAZIONI DI OSSIDORIDUZIONE}
\end{center}

\raggedright % better than "\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}"

Con il termine di ossidoriduzione (o redox) si intende una reazione in cui uno o più elettroni vengono trasferiti da un atomo, uno ione o una molecola a un'altro.

Un esempio di reazione redox è questo
\begin{center}
\schemestart \ce{Ce^{4+} + Fe^{2+}} \arrow{->}
    \ce{Ce^{3+} + Fe^{3+}}\schemestop
\end{center}

In questa reazione un elettrone viene ceduto dal Ferro e acquistato dal Cerio. Il Cerio, che ha una forte affiinità per gli elettroni, viene chiamato \textcolor{blue}{agente ossidante} o \textcolor{blue}{ossidante}, mentre il Ferro, che ha tendenza a cedere elettroni viene chiamato \textcolor{cyan}{agente riducente} o \textcolor{cyan}{riducente}. Per meglio comprendere cosa accade si può scrivere la reazione in questa forma:
\begin{center}
\schemestart \ce{Ce^{4+} + e^{-}}\arrow{->}
    \ce{Ce^{3+}}\schemestop \\ % <--- this is the only place where "\\" is truly needed
\schemestart \ce{Fe^{2+}}\arrow{->}
    \ce{Fe^{3+} + e^{-}}\schemestop
\end{center}
Questa reazione è scritta sotto forma di due \textcolor{brown}{semireazioni}, la prima di riduzione, la seconda di ossidazione. In definitiva, si può dire che il Ferro viene ossidato dal Cerio e, analogamente, il Cerio viene ridotto dal Ferro.

La specie ossidata e quella ridotta costituiscono ciascuna una semicoppia coniugata ossidoriduttiva. Una reazione redox consta quindi di due semicoppie ognuna delle quali partecipa ad una semireazione. In definitiva, una reazione di ossidoriduzione è formata da due semireazioni.

\bigskip % <--- new
\begin{center}
\textcolor{violet}{Celle elettrochimiche}
\end{center}

Le reazioni di ossidoriduzione possono avvenire in due maniere: mettendo a contatto diretto le specie ossidanti e riducenti, oppure mantenendo separate fisicamente le due specie.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.6,keepaspectratio]{Pila.png}
\caption{Pila Daniell}\label{figura:1}
\end{figure}

Il secondo metodo consiste nel realizzare due semicoppie: ad esempio, una lamina di Zn immersa in una soluzione di \ce{ZnSO_{4}} e una lamina di Cu immersa in una soluzione di \ce{CuSO_{4}}. Le due semicoppie costituiscono quindi una cella elettrochimica. Una cella elettrochimica è costituita quindi da due \textcolor[rgb]{0,.6,0}{elettrodi} che nel nostro caso sono costituiti dalle lamine di Zinco e di Rame. I due elettrodi sono collegati ad una lampadina ad incandescenza tramite un filo metallico.

La lamina di Zinco è detto \textcolor[rgb]{0,.6,0}{anodo}, perché è l'elettrodo da cui partono le cariche negative. Lo Zinco metallico presente nella lamina rilascia due elettroni, trasformandosi in ione \ce{Zn^{2+}}, determinando un eccesso di cariche positive nella soluzione che verrà bilanciata tramite il rilascio di anioni solfato da parte del ponte salino di \ce{Na_{2}SO_{4}}.

\clearpage

Gli elettroni cammineranno lungo il filo metallico passando per la resistenza al Tungsteno della lampadina, provocandone l'accensione, per poi giungere alla lamina di Rame, detta \textcolor[rgb]{0,.6,0}{catodo} perché è l'elettrodo che riceve le cariche negative. Questi elettroni vengono acquistati dagli ioni \ce{Cu^{2+}} presenti in soluzione, trasformandosi in Cu metallico che si depositerà nelle pareti del catodo: in questo modo, nella soluzione si avrà un eccesso di cariche negative che verrà bilanciata dai cationi sodio provenienti dal ponte salino.

In definitiva, avvengono le seguenti reazioni: nell'anodo avremo
\begin{center}
\schemestart \ce{Zn{(s)}}\arrow{->[\footnotesize{ox}][]}
     \ce{Zn^{2+} {(aq)} \+ 2e^{-}}\schemestop
\end{center}
mentre nel catodo avremo
\begin{center}
\schemestart \ce{Cu^{2+} {(aq)} \+ 2e^{-}}\arrow{->[\footnotesize{red}][]}
     \ce{Cu{(s)}}\schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is missing. +1 for the “ransom note”. ;-)

Comment: @egreg - Thanks, I'll add the \usepackage directive.

Comment: It's not really that important, because mandatory accents in Italian are always at the end of words, so only a few hyphenation points are missed; on the other hand, trying to use guillemets (that are often used in Italian) without T1 would lead to very poor output. It's better to have T1 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In general, it is bad practice to try to force spacing. You should focus on content and let LaTeX do its thing. If you want to change how things look on all pages, maybe you want to change your margins?

If you really want to add some blank space, you may want to use \vspace. for example,

```
\vspace{1cm}
```

will add a empty vertical space of 1 centimeter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The OP's primary focus seems to be on creating line breaks, rather on vertical whitespace between paragraphs. Can you maybe suggest a way to automate the insertion of vertical whitespace between paragraphs?